# Add Permissions in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql, image, ssms, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to add an image into my database but I keep getting this error:

> You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.

and this is the code I am using:

```
INSERT INTO tblItem ([Image])
    SELECT BulkColumn 
    FROM Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\Users\jakeb\Desktop\Ipod.png', Single_Blob) AS img
```

I've used SSMS before but I can't find the properties on the user when I right click.

Any help please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to grant permissions;

```
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO [login]
```

Alternatively, you can assign the login to the `bulkadmin` role at the server level, not database.

Comment: I used it and it said "securable class 'server'  not supported in this version of SQL Server." I used azure to make the database and server.